# Showing divergence of double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show that the following series diverges ($t$ fixed):
$$\sum_{n > 0} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2t^2}$$

I'm trying to find some way to compare it to a smaller series that diverges, but I'm not getting any results. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You could compare it to an integral to see that it diverges.

Comment: @DanielFischer Do you mean something like $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} \mathop{dx}\mathop{dy}$?

Comment: Something along those lines. Since $m$ traverses all of $\mathbb{Z}$, having one of the integrals extend over $\mathbb{R}$ would be a closer match, but that's immaterial. However, you'd want one of the integrals have a lower bound of $1$ or so ($> 0$) to not produce a singularity in the origin, since for the series, the only problem is at infinity. Then see how you can interpret the sum as an approximation to the integral.

Answer (score 5):

I just found a way:

$$\sum_{n>0} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{m^2+n^2} \ge \sum_{n > 0} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^2+n^2} \ge \sum_{n>0}\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{2n^2}=\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{2n}$$

Answer (score 2):

You may use any of several methods, e.g., the residue theorem, to evaluate the inner sum exactly:

$$\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{m^2+n^2 t^2} = \frac{\pi}{n t} \frac{1+e^{-2 n t}}{1-e^{-2 n t}}$$

The summand over $n$, then, is asymptotically a constant times $1/n$ for large $n$; therefore, the series then may be shown to be bounded from below by

$$\frac{\pi}{t} \sum_{n>0} \frac{1}{n}$$

which diverges.

Comment: Sorry, on what function did you use the residue theorem?

Comment: By an application of the residue theorem, for certain functions $f$: $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\sum_k \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} \pi \cot{(\pi z)} f(z)$$ where the $z_k$ are the non-integer poles of $f$.