# Exercise 6.4 in Stein's Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, upper-lower-bounds, infinite-product

My question is about part (b). The question is as follows:

Let $t>0$ be given and fixed, and define $F(z)$ by

$\displaystyle F(z) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-e^{-2\pi n t}e^{2\pi i z})$

(b) Prove that $F$ vanishes exactly when $z = -int +m$ for $n\geq 1$ and $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, explain why if $z_n$ is an enumeration of these zeros then we have that
$\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{|z_n|^2}= \infty \;\;\;and\;\;\;\sum \frac{1}{|z_n|^{2+\epsilon}}<\infty$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

Proving the first part wasn't too bad. I found that $F(z)=0$ exactly when $z = -int +m$. I'm having a hard time figuring out the second part. How do I show that

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{m^2 +n^2 t^2} =\infty \;\;\;and\;\;\; \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2t^2)^{1+\epsilon/2}}<\infty$

It may be helpful to note that this exercise is in the chapter about Hadamard's theorem.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549121).

Comment: Note that $m^2+t^2n^2 \ge c(m^2+n^2)$ where $c=\max(t^2,1)$ so the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2t^2)^a}$ is majorized by $K\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1}{(m^2+n^2)^a}$ which is easily shown convergent for $a > 1$ by using the integral test and polar coordinates

Comment: Nice, I think that works!

Answer (score 1):

For the divergent series,
$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{m^2 + n^2 t^2}
\ge \sum_{n \ge 1} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m^2 + n^2 t^2}
\ge \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{n}{n^2 + n^2 t^2} = \frac{1}{1+t^2} \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$

Comment: Duplicate: You have asked this question and posted an answer.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate. The linked question does not address the case of the convergent series.